# Is stdin limited in length?

Tags: c++, c, stdin

Are there any stdin input length limitations (in amount of input or input speed)?

Comment: why don't you post the code that's giving you trouble

Comment: question is general. About main rools and concepts.

Comment: The amount of buffered input is determined by the operating system, I think. If the buffer is full, attempted writes can/will block, and if the buffer is empty, attempted reads can/will block. (I'm guessing here).

Comment: It is a stream.  It trickles characters endlessly until the user falls asleep at the keyboard.

Comment: keyboard typing has nothig to do with my instant pasting of 50000 chars=)

Comment: @ole: If it fits onto the clipboard then why don't you think the clipboard memory buffer as the source of the stdin stream?

Comment: 'cat /dev/zero | wc -c'.

if it prints a value, that's the limit. if not, ...

Comment: If you're done with the question, can you please accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends on the stdin driver !

stdin (as a concept) has no limitation.

I expect that kernel developers (of any systems) have made some design choices which add limitations.

Answer (score 9):

**No**. `stdin` has no limits on length or speed.

If you want to get gigabytes of data via `stdin` you can, and your computer will supply it as fast as it can.

Answer (score 2):

According to everyone's other [favorite Q&A site](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Handhelds_-_PDAs/Windows_Mobile/Q_23173553.html):

There shouldn't be a limit to the stream size (whether that's stdin or another). What you might want to check however, is where you store these characters ... Is there enough space to store them all ?

Try just code like this (without storing !) :

```
for (;;) {
    int c = getc(stdin);
    if (c == EOF) { break; }
    putc(c, stdout);
}
```

and see whether it has the same restriction.

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any length limits on `stdin`. If you can't receive large amounts of data it's your code that creates the problems.

Comment: and any SPEED of sending Data limits?

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

The `yes` unix command outputs lines of `y` endlessly. Pipe it to a C program that just reads stdin and puts it on stdout (e.g. `cat`, but `tr 'y' 'y'` also works). Wait until `cat` crashes or your patience reaches its limit:

```
yes | cat
```

About the speed factor, limits are not determined by language or OS but by hardware (CPU, RAM, hard-disk, SATA, network, ...)

Comment: It is used when another command needs confirmation which cannot be disabled (like a hardcoded `rm -i`).

Answer (score 0):

There are limits in the speed of transfer. In general, they are approximately the same as any "UNIX" pipe. There are more efficient mechanisms offered by most operating systems, but pipes are quite fast... assuming you're not using printf & such.